# Error al usar FCM

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-messaging

Se intenta mandar notificaciones en flutter usando FCM, se usa firebase_messaging 6.0.8 en el pubspec.yaml, tambien se creo el archivo Aplication.java para que mande llamar al setPluginRegistrant, el código que lleva dicho archivo es el siguiente:

```
package ............;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Cuando se compila se obtiene este error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on 5003G in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
C:\Users\..................android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\......\Application.java:14: error: cannot access FirebaseMessagingService
       FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
                                      ^
 class file for com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService not found
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14m 33s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score -1):

Revisa las últimas versiones, ya no es necesario tocar el `MainActivity` .

```
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

El proyecto de ejemplo:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/example/MainActivity.java

Y el `AndroidManifest.xml`

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: ya no es necesario crear el archivo Application.java?

Comment: ya no es necesario crear el archivo Application.java?